# Match two annotations in RUTA rule

Tags: uima, ruta, dkpro-core

If I do this in RUTA

```
(W W){->
    LOG("YES you match DOUBLES?")
};
```

then my rule matches on words.  However, if I do this

```
IMPORT PACKAGE de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.syntax.type.dependency
    FROM desc.type.Dependency AS dep;

(dep.Dependency dep.Dependency){->
    LOG("NO match on DOUBLES?")
};
```

then my rule does not match dependencies.  I have also tried `dep.Dependency[2,3]` but that does not match.  I thought it might have something to do with white space between dependencies but this doesn't work either `dep.Dependency WS dep.Dependency`.

I am using ruta-core:2.8.1.  I know I can select single dependencies, so the annotation and my import are correct.  I don't get it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but the rule just work fine as expected in my small test. Can you try if an upgrade to the latest ruta verison helps? Can you provide/link a reproducible example?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upgrade my RUTA to a newer version because it clashes with one of my DKPRO imports.  I am forced to use a compatible version.  Its good to know this should work (its not me!) and in the meantime I created a nearly acceptable work around.